# Possible to configure Windows Live Messenger to open Hotmail in IE with Windows Live Mail installed?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, hotmail, windows-live-mail

If Windows Live Messenger is installed standalone when you click the mail icon it opens Hotmail in the web browser (typically IE). After installing Windows Live Mail clicking the mail icon in Messenger opens Live Mail instead of opening Hotmail in the browser. Is there a way to configure things such that I can leave Windows Live Mail installed but have Messenger open Hotmail in the browser when I click on the mail icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do the same as you and it took me hours to find this!

You do not say  what operating system you are using. The following should work on Vista/7, maybe XP but not 100% certain.

You want to open up Registry Editor and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\Hotmail`

Change `Default` from `Windows Live Mail` to `Windows Live Hotmail`

Next, Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache`

If you have any items called "Windows Live Mail", simply change them to `Windows Live Hotmail`.

Comment: The OS is Vista. I'll give this a try. Thanks.